# Can I just get the first item in a Cursor object (pymongo)?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

so I created a Cursor object by having

```
cdb=self.mongo['bleh_bleh_bleh_setup_here']
data=cdb[collection].find(query_commands_here)
```

Don't worry about the syntax above. Just assume that I can successfully create such cursor object

I know I can do a `for` loop to iterate through the object, but all I want is the very first item of this object. Is there a more efficient way than looping through?

EDIT:

to make things more clear, the 'bleh_bleh_bleh_setup_here' is simply path to connect to the desired mongoDB, and 'query_commands_here' are queries like `{field1:{'$gt':num1}, field2:{'$ne':num2}}` that sort of things. The line

```
data=cdb[collection].find(query_commands_here)
```

will give me a Cursor object that I can iterate with a `for` loop. So things like

```
for item in data:
    print item
```

will print out each of the entry in the object. It works nicely. However, according to the documentation, this cursor object should have method called `.hasNext()`, which should return True if there's a next entry. So far, I haven't found a way to get it to work for some odd reason. `data.next()` does give me an entry though. I want to make sure I can have that condition to make sure I don't call `.next()` for a cursor object that contains nothing, though I don't foresee this kind of situation happening, but I would assume it'd occur at some point.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[`.find_one()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one) would return you a single document matching the criteria:

```
cdb[collection].find_one(query_commands_here)
```

---

Note that the [PyMongo Cursor](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html) does not have a `hasNext()` method. What I would do is to call `cursor.next()` and handle the `StopIteration` exception:

```
try:
    record = cursor.next()
except StopIteration:
    print("Empty cursor!")
```

Comment: Thanks! Right now I want to retain all the info in the Cursor object while just retrieving some information from the first entry (since I'd have a sort command in the `.find`). Would it be efficient enough to use `cdb[collection].find()` and another line with `cdb[collection].find_one(query_command_here, sort[('field_to_sort': -1)]`?

Comment: or rather, all I want is one field of that `find_one` result. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @JChao I think you may just be alright with a single `find()` command. You can call `cursor.next()` to get the first record and then call [`cursor.rewind()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.rewind) to reset it's state. I personally have not tried that though - please test carefully and log the queries sent to the server. Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting `AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'hasNext'` when I try to check if there's a `next` for the object. I don't know why this line won't work. `data.next()` and `data.hasNext()` both return errors

Comment: @JChao interesting, `cursor.next()` should work..could you provide the complete code you have and the traceback? Thanks.

Comment: There's actually not much else that's worth mentioning. The only two lines that are in effect currently are the `cdb=self.mongo['bleh_bleh_bleh_setup_here']` and `data=cdb[collection].find(query_commands_here)` the query command is just a combination of requirements like `{field1:{'$gt':num1}, field2:{'$ne':num2}}` while the mongo setup is just path to connect. Now I want to add that `.next` into the line below `data=cdb[collection].find(query_commands_here)` so I can extract some information out of the first query

Comment: Hey @alecxe would you take a look of my EDIT in the main post? I think I added in all the info needed....hopefully

Comment: @JChao thank you for the additional information, made an update, hope it helps.

Comment: thanks. I found a workaround by using c[i], with i being the index #. This calls the __getitem__ function which works nicely for my situation.

Comment: cursor.next() is useful when using aggregations, where you get result as list

Answer (score 2):

You can also do the following *(without having to handle the* `StopIteration` *exception)*:

```
cur = cdb[collection].find(query_commands_here)
record = next(cur, None)
if record:
    # Do your thing
```

This works because python's built in next() will return the default value when it hits the end of the iterator.